# ASP.NET 4.0 Server Control: Handling server control propertyChanged in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-controls

I am trying to build an ASP.NET custom server control. I am using .NET framework 4.0. All I want is to  be notified in my JavaScript function, about the values being changed on the server. Or, even better, if I can get my JavaScript model in sync with the server side model. i.e. whenever a property of my server side model changes, the corresponding property of my JavaScript model also gets updated.

I have been searching through MSDN for something like this, but no clear explanation on this topic.

How can I achieve this? Pointing to some relevant articles would be very helpful. And one more thing, I don't want to use update panel, as it will go through executing Page_Load method again and again.

Comment: Maybe look at SignalR, AngularJS / KnockoutJS ?

Comment: Also try looking at Single Page Application (SPA) features in asp.net since synchronization is something that is often used in SPA.